# How can I search custom header in Elasticsearch apm?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elk, apm

I have a quick question I can not use custom headers for searching by below code. But it is not working.

```
http.request.headers["correlationId"]: "d7fc64cf-d176-4a17-9a8f-66c21b48265d"
```

is it possible by writing any query for searching above code in elasticsearch apm search free text field?

Comment: Is this how it is stored in Elasticsearch? Can you grab the source of an example document and add it to the question? Then we can probably build the right query.